# Fourier Coefficients and an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, parsevals-identity

I've been given the piecewise function (on period interval $]-\pi,\pi]$ 
$$f(x) =   \begin{cases} 
  \pi & x=\pi \\
  x & 0\leq x < \pi \\
        0 & -\pi<x<0
  \end{cases}
  $$

And was asked to find its Fourier coefficients, and then to derive the formula $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ based on this.

I found the Fourier coefficients (with regards to $e^{inx}$)
$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(y)e^{-iny} \, dy =\cdots = \frac{\pi n i (-1)^n + (-1)^n-1}{2\pi n^2}$$ with $c_0=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(y) \, dy = \frac{\pi}{4}$

I then tried to use Parseval's identity $\sum |c_n|^2 = \|f\|^2$, (where $\|f\|^2=\pi/4$), but have gotten a little stuck.

$$|c_0|^2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n|^2 + |c_{-n}|^2 = \pi/4$$
$$\pi/4 - \pi^2/16 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg|\frac{\pi n i (-1)^n + (-1)^n-1}{2\pi n^2} \bigg|^2 + \bigg|\frac{\pi (-n) i (-1)^{(-n)} + (-1)^n-1}{2\pi (-n)^2}\bigg|^2$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg|\pi n i (-1)^n + (-1)^n-1\bigg|^2 + \bigg|\pi (-n) i (-1)^{(-n)} + (-1)^n-1\bigg|^2$$

And now am a little uncertain how to go forward.
I've noticed that for n=1,2,3... the series value is $2\pi^2+8... 2\pi^2...2\pi^2+4/9$...
(Where I haven't applied the $\frac{1}{4\pi^2}$ factor), but I'm not quite sure how to categorize this.

Comment: There's a major typo in the definition of $f$...

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've fixed that now.

Comment: @Woodenplank : If the difference between $||f||$ and $\|f\|$ is not conspicuous to you, look at the difference between $||f|| ||g||$ and $\|f\|\|g\|.$ I edited accordingly. I also changed $A=...=Z$ to $A=\cdots=Z.$ If you don't want the dots centered you can write $A=\ldots=Z$ rather than $A=...=Z.$ If you type $A=...=Z$ rather than $A=\ldots=Z$ in actual LaTeX rather than in MathJax (which is what is used here) then you will see something that looks like $A=\text{...}=Z $ instead of $A=\ldots=Z. \qquad$